# What would likely cause directories in /var/run to disappear / not be created on startup? (CentOS 7.3)

Tags: centos, process, systemd, startup, var

Ran into an issue today where Apache would not load because `/var/run/httpd` was missing. After much hunting to [find](https://ma.ttias.be/apache-2-4-ah01762-ah01760-failed-to-initialize-shm-shared-memory-segment) that cause of the error I was getting (`[Tue Jul 25 00:06:31.574386 2017] [auth_digest:error] [pid 6179] (2)No such file or directory: AH01760: failed to initialize shm - all nonce-count checking, one-time nonces, and MD5-sess algorithm disabled`).

Then I saw that MariaDB was missing its `/var/run/mysql` directory, and PostgreSQL was [missing](https://serverfault.com/q/766287/2321) its directory.

What would cause those to not be made on system start-up / saved between reboots?

I would not *expect* to need to modify init scripts as suggested in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2109/6388).

#### Edit: outputs of `ls -dl /var/run` & `ls -dl /run`

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 6 Dec 15  2015 /var/run -> ../run
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root 800 Jul 26 03:40 /run
```

Comment: something does not add up. was your var filled up and you took care of it? are you low in memory? is run or /var/run in disk or ram?

Comment: add also the output of free -m please

Comment: @bbb31 - `tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not a fix - but a fix.

After trawling through other SE network sites, forums, newsgroups, and the like, I wondered if it might be related to mount order for local and remote file systems (there are a pair of CIFS shares mounted on this server, which each have subdirectories bind mounted elsewhere).

I pushed the CIFS shares higher in `/etc/fstab`, and moved all bind mounts to the bottom.

Then I rebooted.

Now `/run` aka `/var/run` is working as expected.

I don't *know* that editing `/etc/fstab` mattered - but it's the only substantive change made that I know of.

Answer (score 3):

{/var,}/run is vaporized by systemd on boot.  It's a wonderful and entirely unexpected surprise with such low value.

If you want to ensure a directory exists after boot, you'll have to hook something in with the tmpfiles section of systemd.

```
/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/httpd.conf
::::::::::::::
d /run/httpd   710 root apache
d /run/httpd/htcacheclean   700 apache apache

/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/mariadb.conf
::::::::::::::
d /var/run/mariadb 0755 mysql mysql -
```

And, if your tmpfiles entries are missing, I'm betting you hand-roll your own packages (and tune, and test, and promote, for every.single.release).  As long as we agree it's usually a bad idea for anything with scale or an SLA, that's cool though.

Answer (score 1):

These config files reside /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d and /etc/tmpfiles.d/.

I needed to unmask and enable the systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service in order to have /run automatically setup at boot:

`systemctl unmask systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
systemctl enable systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`

Answer (score 0):

/var/run is considered to be a volatile and temporary directory.

`tmpfiles.d` is for the configuration for creation, deletion and cleaning of volatile and temporary files, which includes directories in `/var/run`

Files in `/etc/tmpfiles.d` override files with the same name in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d` and `/run/tmpfiles.d`.  Files in `/etc/tmpfiles.d` are reserved for the local administrator, who may use this logic to override the configuration files installed by vendor packages.
source: https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-tmpfiles.d/

You can `cat` existing configs in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d` and `ls -l /var/run`  permissions to help determine appropriate permissions.

create a new file `[name]` or `httpd` in `/etc/tmpfiles.d`;
example based on `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/screen`

httpd

```
# httpd  needs directory in /run  
d /run/httpd 0775 root apache
```

generic

```
# [name] needs directory in /run  
d /run/[name] [perms] [user] [group]
```